# Standard way of implementing remote source jquery autocomplete

Tags: web-services, web-applications, autocomplete

I have around 1M string elements against which I have to provide autocomplete. I certainly can't transfer the list to client so have to do remote source autocomplete.

Now, what is the standard way - data structure/ algo of implementing the server side of remote source autocomplete. How should I handle the ajax request sent by client for autocomplete? **Should I store the list in database, or keep it in RAM in some specific data structure ..etc?**

I feel keeping it in database would slow it down too much, but keeping it in RAM would conflict with limited RAM issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get very acceptable response times for Autocomplete from a remote database.  For example, geonames.org has about 6 million location names.  Most people, me included, get sub second response times to display the Autocomplete dropdown selection.

Here is a link to a tutorial about how to build the database, the server manager (in several languages), and the Autocomplete code.

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/29/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-php-and-mysql/